# str.contains function AND does not contain

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm iterating over all values in columns that contain 'Applicant Age' and adding them into a new column.

```
for i in range(17):
    rule_col = f'rule{i}_evaluationstring'
    matches = df_merged[rule_col].astype(str).str.contains('Applicant Age', na=False)
    df_merged.loc[matches, 'applicant_age'] = df_merged.loc[matches, rule_col]
```

This works properly, but there are some entries that have an 'Applicant Age = 200' that I would like to omit.

How do I add an additional function that omits all values that contain 200 while keeping the functionality of the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bitwise operators `&` (and) and `~` (not) in combination.
The syntax looks like `df.loc[(condition_A) & (~condition_B)]`

An example relevant for your question would be:

```
df = df_merged

selected = df.loc[
    (df[rule_col].astype(str).str.contains('Applicant Age', na=False)) &
    (~df[rule_col].astype(str).str.contains('200', na=False))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
matches = (df_merged[rule_col].astype(str).str.contains('Applicant Age', na=False)) & (~df_merged[rule_col].astype(str).str.contains('Applicant Age = 200', na=False))
```